# Animated Webix chart

Tags: animation, charts, webix

like other chart tools, is there any option to develop animated webix charts,
Animation like
When Loading rotation of Donut,
Click to Zoom,
Block Seperation in pie,
Label Ruler in pie,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that Webix Charts are not the best choice if you want charts with animation effects and other visually complex things. Webix Charts are great for loading, presenting, grouping, filtering data, and for CRUD operations on them, but they are not as sophisticated as charts from some other libraries that are dedicated to charts specifically.

Webix allows for [third-party components integration](https://webix.com/integrations/). That's why I would recommend you to use some other library charts and integrate them into your Webix UI. You can use some of the ready-made integrations from [this repository](https://github.com/webix-hub/components) and you are very welcome to contribute your integration. You can use these guides in the process:

- https://docs.webix.com/desktop__chart_integration.html
- https://blog.webix.com/using-third-party-libraries-with-webix-ui/

Comment: what are all you said is absolute correct, i just want to clarify my doubt that is what i post this question, thank you for your reply